# How to make page numbers in a nomenclature hyperref links?

Tags: hyperref, nomenclature

I want to create a nomenclature for a very large document using the nomencl.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\nomenclature[N]{$N$}{some number}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

This correctly creates the Output:

[image: output]

Is it possible to make nomencl understand that hyperref is available such that 'page 1' or just '1' is a hyperlink you can click on and are actually referred to page 1?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to redefine the command `\pagedeclaration` defined by `\nomencl`. Please note that the original definition of `\pagedeclaration` depends on your selected language.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref}
\def\pagedeclaration#1{, \hyperlink{page.#1}{page\nobreakspace#1}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
a
\clearpage
b
\nomenclature[N]{$N$}{some number}
\clearpage
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great! @MarcoDaniel , Is there a way to right-align the page numbers and fill the space (between items and their page numbers) with dots?

Comment: I think I figured it out! I should use:   \def\pagedeclaration#1{, \dotfill\hyperlink{page.#1}{page\nobreakspace#1}}