# How to add page numbering in nomenclature to link to an arbitrary page with a "label"?

Tags: nomenclature, hyperlink, nomencl, pageref

I like to create a nomenclature that shows a page number (with `\pageref` or `\hyperlink`, etc) pointing to a page elsewhere that I assigned a label. Possibly, this label should be an argument to the nomenclature command.

In a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197166/how-to-make-page-numbers-in-a-nomenclature-hyperref-links?rq=1) it is possible to add page numbers to nomenclature, but they place the number of the page where `\nomenclature` itself is located at. While, I need to assign the page myself.

The motivation for this question is that I write all my nomenclatures in one file, say `symbols.tex`, like

```
% In symbolds.tex
% We have groups of symbols (here S, and P)
\nomenclature[S,001]{$N$}{Integer}{\ref{numencl:N}}
\nomenclature[P,001]{$M$}{Another integer}{\ref{numencl:M}}
```

and include them before any chapter starts (`\include{symbolds.tex}`). This way I can reorder and regroup the entries better in a large document. Later in each chapter, I add anchors (`\label`) to places where a variable is first defined. I like the nomenclature to know where to find the page number to the labels that are placed forward in the document. Something like

```
% In symbolds.tex
\nomenclature[S,001]{$N$}{An integer}{\ref{numencl:N}}

% Later in a chapter
The variable $N$ \label{nomencl:N} is ...
```

Here is an example

```
% In main.tex

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Nomenclature stuff
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage[backref=page,pageanchor]{hyperref}

% I am not sure I need the next line, this is from the linked stack exchange page above
\def\pagedeclaration#1{, \dotfill\hyperlink{page.#1}{\nobreakspace#1}} 
\makenomenclature

% Grouping symbols
usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{S}{Sets}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{P}{Symbols}{}}%
]}
% ------------------

\begin{document}

% Some fillers here (title page, abstract, table of content, list of figures, etc.
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

% Here is the nomenclature
\include{symbols}
\clearpage
\printnomenclature

% Chapters start
\chapter{Introduction}
Let $N$ be an integer \label{nomencl:N} ... and $M$ another integer \label{nomencl:M} defined by ...

\end{document}
```

I am wondering how I can renew `\nomenclature` or other related commands, so that it accept `\label{nomencl:N}`) as an option.

If this is not possible, what is a feasible solution to place a reference to an arbitrary page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `\nomenclature` command use a label as a page reference you can modify the command to accept an extra argument `#4`. The command is defined in `nomencl.sty` as a sequence of commands: `\nomenclature` calls `\@nomenclature` which calls `\@@nomenclature` which finally calls `\@@@nomenclature`. This last command is where the actual formatting is done. The original command contains the line

```
|nompageref}{\thepage}}%
```

which is interpreted as "put the `\nompageref` command in the output with `\thepage` as argument", where `\thepage` is expanded to the page number where the command is called. You can change this to call a different command with a different argument. An easy way seems to be to just call `\pageref` with an extra command `#4`. However, this does not work because the original command `\nompageref` contains some extra code at the end that is necessary for the processing of the nomenclature. Therefore you can define a new command (called `\nomlabelref` in the code below) to contain a space, the `\pageref`, and the extra code, and call that new command within `\@@@nomenclature`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\makeatletter
\def\nomlabelref#1{\ \pageref{#1}\nomentryend\endgroup}
\def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3#4{%
 \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}\def\@tempc{#4}%
 \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
  {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa @[{\nom@verb\@tempa}]%
      \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
        |nomlabelref}{\@tempc}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack}
\makeatother
\usepackage[backref=page,pageanchor]{hyperref}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\nomenclature[S,001]{$N$}{Integer}{nomencl:N}
\nomenclature[P,001]{$M$}{Another integer}{nomencl:M}
first page
\printnomenclature
\clearpage
second page

Let $N$ be an integer \label{nomencl:N} ... and $M$ another integer \label{nomencl:M} defined by ...
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I did not use `#4` directly, but instead I defined a temporary variable `\@tempc`, to be consistent with the rest of the definition (which defines `\@tempa` and `\@tempb` for `#2` and `#3`).

---

In response to the comment: you can check for an empty argument and remove the pageref in that case. Because `makeindex` requires an argument you can use a dummy value like `1`. Then in `\makelabelref` you can check for this value and print the pageref only when the argument is an actual label. The check uses `\ifnum1=0#1` which works for numbers and for strings, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306500/.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\makeatletter
% if argument is 1 do nothing, else print pageref
\def\nomlabelref#1{\ifnum1=0#1\relax\else\ \pageref{#1}\fi\nomentryend\endgroup}
\def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3#4{%
 \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}\def\@tempc{#4}%
 \ifx\@tempc\@empty\def\@tempc{1}\fi% set dummy value if argument is empty
 \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
  {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa @[{\nom@verb\@tempa}]%
      \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
        |nomlabelref}{\@tempc}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack}
\makeatother
\usepackage[backref=page,pageanchor]{hyperref}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\nomenclature[A,001]{$N$}{Integer}{nomencl:N}
\nomenclature[B,001]{$M$}{Another integer}{nomencl:M}
\nomenclature[C,001]{$Z$}{Yet another integer}{}
first page
\printnomenclature
\clearpage
second page

Let $N$ be an integer \label{nomencl:N} ... and $M$ another integer \label{nomencl:M} defined by ...
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This hack is an excellent solution. Is it possible to make the fourth argument optional? There are some symbols that might not need to be linked to any specific page. I am wondering if the signature of `\nomenclature` can fall back to no 4th option, or perhaps accept a null input `{}` on the last option.

Comment: @Sia see edit for using an empty argument.

Comment: Dear Marijn, do you know if there is a way to adapt your solution to my recent question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586422 ? :-)

Comment: (OK, I just found a way to solve my problem!)